# Graphs with many edges avoided by Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

Let $G$ be a $3$-connected Hamiltonian graph with at least one edge that belongs to each H-cycle of $G$. Some authors (e.g. in the link given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190239/smallest-planar-cubic-graph-with-non-hamiltonian-edge)) call such an edge an **a-edge** and an edge that belongs to no H-cycle of $G$ a **b-edge**. Let $a(G)$ and $b(G)$ denote the number of a-edges and b-edges, respectively. Define $\rho(G)=\dfrac{b(G)}{a(G)} $.

> - Are there good (or even sharp) upper bounds for $\rho(G)$ ? Maybe $\rho(G)<1$?

Such graphs can be constructed e.g. using certain non-Hamiltonian graphs like the so-called Tutte fragment $T$ or the “Petersen fragment” $P$, the latter obtained from the Petersen graph by adding a vertex on each of three consecutive edges and an edge leaving at each of those vertices. These edges are labelled by $1,2,3$.

[image: T & P]
It is easy to see that $T$ does not admit a H-path between 1 and 3, whereas $P$ admits no H-path starting at 2, only two H-paths between 1 and 3 (one consists of the violet and the red edges, the other one of the violet and the black edges). $T$ has two a-edges (marked in violet) and no b-edges; $P$ has nine a-edges (violet) and three b-edges (light blue).
The simplest $3$-connected Hamiltonian graphs obtained from these are a prism over the big “triangle” of $T$ with $a(G)=3$ and $b(G)=0$ (note that this one is even planar) and likewise a prism over $P$, which has $a(G)=16$ and $b(G)=5$.

By taking a Hamiltonian graph and replacing certain cubic vertices by $T$ or $P$, we can impose restrictions on the H-cycles and obtain graphs with various values of $a(G)$ and $b(G)$.
If we start with the wheel $W_{n}$ and replace one vertex by a $T$ in such a way that the spike becomes an a-edge, the resulting graph 'keeps' only two of the H-cycles of $W_n$ and has $\rho(G)=\dfrac{n-3}{n}$. I wonder if this is best possible. So if generally $\rho(G)<1$ holds, that would be sharp.

**What about the maximum if we consider only cubic graphs ?**
If we start with the prism over $K_3$ and make one ‘vertical' edge a b-edge by replacing one vertex with a $P$, we get a graph with a unique$^*$ H-cycle and $\rho(G)=\dfrac{5}{13}\approx.3846 $.
If we start with the dodecahedron and 'block' three well chosen edges (i.e. make them into b-edges) by replacing three vertices with $P$'s, we get a graph with a unique$^*$ H-cycle and $\rho(G)=\dfrac{16}{41}\approx.3902 $, slightly larger.
Starting with a [truncated icosahedron (soccerball)](http://snkhan.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5972), we can still do better. It depends on how many edges have to be blocked by using $P$'s to remain with a unique$^*$ H-cycle: if there are $k$ such edges and the resulting graph $G$ is unique$^*$ Hamiltonian, it will have $\rho(G)=\dfrac{30+2k}{60+7k} $, which is equal to $\dfrac{16}{41}$ for $k=9$ and gets bigger as $k$ decreases. I've checked that $k=7$, thus $\rho(G)=\dfrac{44}{109}\approx.4037 $, is possible. (Note that in the drawing given in the link, only the green and black 1-factors yield a H-cycle.)

$^*$  *Edit: "unique" is meant w.r.t. the H-cycles of the original graph, because inside the instances of $P$ there are of course several ways of making H-paths through them.*

Of course I don't claim that this method yields the best possible results. So the question:

> - Are there cubic, 3-connected graphs with $\rho(G)$ even bigger than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first counterexample given by @joro gives rise to the following family $G_k$ of graphs with $\rho(G_k)=k$ :
$G_k$ has $n=4k+3$ vertices numbered $0,1,\dots,n-1$ forming a H-cycle (imagine a regular n-gon embedded such that the vertex $2k+1$ is on the bottom), plus the ‘horizontal’ chords $(2j-1,4k+3-2j)$ for $j=1,...,k$ (call their set $B$) and the other chords $(j,2k+1+j)$ for $j=0,...,2k+1$. It is not hard to see that $(4k+2,0)$ is an a-edge. As the graph without this edge and without $B$ is bipartite, all edges of $B$ must be b-edges. It remains to check that for each other edge, there is a H-cycle that doesn’t contain it.

For the **second question**, as @Martin Tancer and @nvcleemp have pointed aout, $\rho(G)\le1/2$ for cubic graphs. The following construction comes arbitrarily close to $1/2$ :

For $n=2k$, start with a H-cycle $0,...,2k-1,0$ and add the ‘horizontal’ chords $(j,2k-j)$ for $j=1,...,k-1$ and the ‘vertical’ chord $(0,k)$. Replace the vertex $k$ with an instance of $P$ that blocks the vertical chord. Then it is easy to see (starting at the vertex $0$) that the horizontal chords cannot be part of a H-cycle. So this graph has $a(G)=2k+7$ (the original cycle plus 7 inner edges of $P$) and $b(G)=k+1$ (the horizontal chords plus 2 inner edges of $P$).

So both original questions are answered, thanks to your input. Remains the interesting question raised by joro **what can be said about $\rho(G)$ for 4-regular graphs**.

Comment: You mean the chords are modulo n? Verified with program for small $k$.

Comment: Yes  modulo n, but the way I've written it, you don't even need that. I don't have time right now to add a diagram for say k=2 or k=3, but you can easily draw one. For checking that the edges (i,i+1) for i=0,...,n-2 aren't a-edges, it suffices to note that there are 2 H-cycles (symmetric to each other w.r.t. the vertical axis) which alternate essentially between diagonals of the n-gon and edges of it.

Comment: OK. Here is a drawing for k=3:  http://s27.postimg.org/wwx38t3w3/graph_k_3.png

Answer (score 4):

The computer found counterexamples to $\rho(G)<1$.

Despite verification, I am not sure this is correct.

$G_1$ on $7$ vertices, $G_2$ on $11$ vertices.
$\rho(G_1)=1,\rho(G_2)=2$

$G_1$:

```
edges=[(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 6)]
A=[(0, 3)]
B=[(4, 6)]
```

$G_2$:

```
edges=[(0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 7), (3, 9), (3, 10), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 9), (5, 10), (6, 8), (7, 10)]
A=[(0, 5)]
B=[(6, 8), (7, 10)]
```

Plot of $G_1$:

[image: G_1]

Comment: Thank you. Why should this not be correct? There are interesting patterns in your 2 graphs, which might allow (at least worth a try) to restrict further searches for even higher $\rho(G)$'s: Put $V=V_3\cup V_4$ (vertices of degree 3 and 4). Did you notice that G1 and G2 are "almost bipartite", the vertices of $V_3$ essentially alternating in each H-cycle with those of $V_4$. At the exception of 03 (05 for G2), which is... an a-edge! And the only edges in $\langle V_4\rangle$ are the b-edges. H-cycle e.g. for G1: 0 4 2 6 1 5 3, for G2: 0 6 2 8 1 7 3 9 4 10 5.

Comment: @Wolfgang if you trust my program, there are no cubic counterexamples rho(G) > 1 on less than 20 vertices.

Comment: Also note that displaying your $G_1$ and $G_2$ like you would display bipartite graphs, it is almost immediately clear why the a-edges and b-edges are what they are. BTW do you have a feeling that $\rho(G)$ is bounded?

Comment: For cubic ones, I conjecture $rho(G)\le 1/2$. Have you found cubic graphs with bigger rho?

Comment: @Wolfgang For cubic the largest I found so far is $3/8$.

Comment: @Wolfgang Re bounded rho. Don't know. Maybe a gadget with certain properties can make it unbounded, don't know for what gadget to search.

Comment: Isn't $\rho(G) \leq 1/2$ somewhat trivial? A $b$-edge in a cubic graph is incident to four $a$-edges.  Each $a$-edge comes this way from at most two $b$-edges.

Comment: @Martin Yes, you are right! An easy counting argument. I had thought of b-edges as restricted to chords of a H-cycle, but that approach doesn't lead very far as each H-cycle may (and even must) contain edges which are not a-edges. So it is all about how close a 3-regular graph can come to that limit.

Comment: I agree with Martin that the upper bound of $\frac{1}{2}$ is 'trivial' for cubic graphs. If a vertex is incident with a $b$-edge, than the other two edges incident to that vertex are $a$-edges, so for each $b$-edge, there are at least 2 $a$-edges.

Comment: @joro May I ask you to check the following two graphs on 11 vertices: G1 has a H-cycle 0 1 ... 10 0, further paths 0-5-10, 6-1-9-4, 2-7-3-8. G2 the same H-cycle and then paths 0-5-10, 6-3-7-4, 8-1-9-2. If one (or maybe even both) have 0-10 as a-edge and 1-9 and 3-7 as b-edges, then we may have found a "gadget".

Comment: @Wolfgang Will try to check them tomorrow. You will save me typing/errors if you give me the explicit edges in a format close to the answer.

Comment: @joro There you go: G1=[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(8,9),(9,10),(10,0), (0,5),(5,10),(6,1),(1,9),(9,4),(2,7),(7,3),(3,8)]

G2=[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(8,9),(9,10),(10,0), (0,5),(5,10),(8,1),(1,9),(9,2),(4,7),(7,3),(3,6)]         If only tomorrow, I'm looking forward to the result when I'm online again after my Christmas break  :)

Comment: @Wolfgang For both graphs got rho(G)=2. For both A,B=[(0, 10)],[(1, 9), (3, 7)].  Do you have infinitely many graphs with rho>=1 or rho>=2?

Comment: @joro: I verified your values for the graphs in the answe, and for the two graphs in Wolfgang's comment.

Comment: I have also ran my program for cubic graphs on up to 20 vertices. The largest $\rho$-value I found, was for a graph on 20 vertices which had $\frac{2}{5}$. The graph6 string for that graph is S?hW@eOGKCGA?_??_???RO?G?CG?D??AK

Comment: @nvcleemp Verified your graph6 string. What about $4$-regular? Can't find any on up to 12 vertices having both a and b edges.

Comment: I'll have to have a look: I currently don't have a program to convert the output of genreg to the input format for my program. If I have some time tomorrow, I'll write one, but now I'm leaving for the rest of the day.

Comment: @nvcleemp I am searching with sage and for graph generation nauty's geng. From the sage bugtracking system learnt there are serious bugs in graphs and this is why I doubted the verification with sage.

Comment: @joro geng's not that suited for generating regular graphs. Which bugs are you talking about? There are always bugs, but I don't know of any that are that serious that you should doubt your verification. That being said, it is always a good idea to have an independent verification of any program.

Comment: @nvcleemp Agreed about independent verification. IIRC there was a bug which totally screwed graphs if the vertices are sets (check http://trac.sagemath.org/ or Changelogs ). Basically I am paranoid there might be other unknown bugs. For this case was too lazy to verify it with something else.

Comment: hmm, I don't think vertices can be sets, since they need to be hashable. Maybe that's the bug to which you're referring. It's been a couple of months since I really had the time to go through the tickets at trac.sagemath.org

Comment: @nvcleemp Might be wrong about the exact bug, but there was graph issue when comparing sets.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12121/discussion-between-joro-and-nvcleemp)

Comment: I moved the discussion to chat.